# Can we share PDF with drawings in other applications using PDFKit in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, share, pdfkit, uidocumentinteractioncontroller

I am using `PDFKit` to edit, draw and then share `PDFs` in other applications like mail, WhatsApp, etc.. Able to share the file after editing but when I try to share the `PDF` after drawing something, I am unable to share it. Those drawings are not there in the `PDF` after sharing. Please tell me, can we share the `PDF` with drawings using `PDFKit`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you save your pdf file into the local storage and next the easiest approach would be to use the UIActivityViewController to share the file.

Comment: Yes, I saved and I'm using DocumentInteractionController to share but nothing worked

Comment: Use UIActivityViewController.

Comment: No, we should use UIDocumentInteractionController. I am able to share but the drawings are not there in the shared file. That's my problem

Comment: Why you need to stick to UIDocumentInteractionController? Their interface is the same, popover from the bottom.

Comment: I was unable to share in some applications when I used UIActivityViewController and that's not at all a prblm. I can share the PDF with all editing operations except this draw